# Pipelined loop on Cortex-A7 slower then naive

Tags: optimization, arm, inline-assembly

I'm executing the following two bignum multiplication routines on a Raspberry Pi 2 (I think) using gcc inline assembler. Each of these is supposed to do the inner part of a schoolboy multiplication.

First routine is essentially

```
loop:
ldr %r6, [%3]  ;load the result
ldr %r5, [%0], #4 ; and the other arg
umaal %r6, %r4, %r5, %2 ;do the mult with carry
str %r5, [%3], #4
subs %1, 1
bne loop
```

The second routine is a software pipelined implementation. Below is the intrinsic assembler, so some quotes and newlines are there.

```
"mov     r4, #0\n"
"mov     r11, %3\n"
"cmp     %1, #4\n"
"ble     3f\n"

/* Prologue */
"ldr     r5, [r11], #4\n"
"ldr     r6, [%0], #4\n" /* load k */
"ldr     r7, [r11], #4\n"
"ldr     r8, [%0], #4\n" /* load k+1 */
"umaal   r5, r4, r6, %2\n" /* mult k*/
/* Pipelined loop*/
"2:\n"
"ldr     r9, [r11], #4\n" 
"ldr     r10, [%0], #4\n" /*load k+2*/
"umaal   r7, r4, r8, %2\n" /*mult k+1 */
"str     r5, [%3], #4\n"  /*store k */
"ldr     r5, [r11], #4\n"
"ldr     r6, [%0], #4\n" /* load k+3*/
"umaal   r9, r4, r10, %2\n" /*mult k+2 */
"str     r7, [%3], #4\n" /*store k+1*/
"ldr     r7, [r11], #4\n"
"ldr     r8, [%0], #4\n" /*load k+4*/
"umaal   r5, r4, r6, %2\n" /*mult k+3*/
"str     r9, [%3], #4\n" /*store k+2*/
"sub     %1, #3\n"
"cmp     %1, #4\n"
"bgt     2b\n"
/*Epiloge*/
"sub     %1, #2\n" /*adjust iterations*/
"umaal   r7, r4, r8, %2\n" /*mult k+4*/
"str     r5, [%3], #4\n" /*store k+3*/
"str     r7, [%3], #4\n" /*store k+4*/


/*Cleanup loop*/
"3:\n"
"cmp     %1, 0\n"
"beq     5f\n"
"4:\n"
"ldr     r5, [r11], #4\n"
"ldr     r6, [%0], #4\n"
"umaal   r5, r4, r6, %2\n"
"str     r5, [%3], #4\n"
"subs    %1, #1\n"
"bne     4b\n"

"5:\n"
"str     r4, [%3]\n"
```

The second one is significantly slower then the first, by about 20%, and I don't understand why: the pipelining is supposed to ensure the load and multiply latencies are hidden by the pipeline. Are there hazards I don't know about?

Comment: That formatting you've offered doesn't help with readability...

Comment: _"...supposed to ensure the load and multiply latencies are hidden by the pipeline."_ - you know [Cortex-A7 is a simple _in-order_ pipeline](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0464f/BABDAHCE.html), right? When you're going to be spending most of the time just waiting for loads either way, other things like the code fitting in a single L1 cache line, not having to spill almost all the registers to the stack, and likely being trivial for the branch predictor to get right are almost certainly not disadvantages.

Comment: @Notlikethat Even classical pipelined in-order machines will avoid stalling on a load-instruction until the result of that load is used, hiding *some* latency and allowing cache-misses to be overlapped (concurrent rather than consecutive). This doesn't require full out-of-order, just a couple of shadow-registers and checkpointing.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=154553  Not completely shown there, but simple alignment can result in wide differences in performance with the same machine code.  You have not nearly provided enough information, what was your min/max performance on each machine code blob?  Was the 20% the delta between the slowest of the first and the fastest of the second or the fastest of the first and slowest of the second?

Comment: I think there was an SO question as well on performance adding removing one/few instructions wasnt reflected in the performance timers, problem of course was dram is painfully slow and the pipe was starving on a single shot test.  Are you running this in a loop tens of thousands of times?  Caches on/off?  Of course fetch alignment and cache alignment, is this inline assembly, what about real assembly that you can control a bit better?  How and where are you timing it, etc?

Comment: So unfortunately I have rather limited measuring procedures. This is the inner loop of a complex operation I am running a whole bunch of, and averaging. I'll see what can be done about alignment, and will try real assembly or just chucking it at the compiler in C and seeing what it does.